# Output of a Function is zero not a vector

Tags: r, function

When I recall this function, its output is zero. The x in output should be a vector containing 365 values based on timepoints from 1 to 365. Maybe there is something wrong with the function definition or returning values.

```
vax_fun = function(timepoint, parms1){
  with (
    as.list (parms1),
    {
      if (timepoint < T0){
          v_t = 0
          return((v_t))
      } else if (timepoint <= T1){
        v_t = timepoint * (exp(tetha)-C_0)/(T1-T0) + C_0 - T0 * (exp(tetha)-C_0)/(T1-T0)
          return((v_t))
      }else if (timepoint <= T2){
          v_t = (exp(tetha)* timepoint)
          return((v_t))
      } else if (timepoint <= T3){
          v_t = -timepoint * (exp(tetha)-C_1)/(T3-T2) + C_1 - T3 * (exp(tetha)-C_1)/(T3-T2)
          return((v_t))
      } else {
          v_t=0
          return((v_t))
      }
    }
  )
}
```

```
parms1=c(
  
  T0=55,
  T1=115,
  T2=175,
  T3=235,
  threshold = 275,
  tetha = 5,
  C_0 = 100,
  C_1 = 100

)

for (timepoint in 1:365){
  x = vax_fun(timepoint, parms1)
  x
}
```

Comment: You want `v_t = 0` or `v_t <- 0` (assignment), not `v_t == 0` (logical test).

Comment: I am not an r expert but do you mean to have two equals on the v_t==0 before the return statement?  If you change that to an assignment of v_t=0 does that help?

Answer (score 2):

In the first if case, and in your else, you have v_t == 0, which is a boolean, right?  Should just be one =

Comment: Still, the output x is zero. It should a vector consistent of 365 values I am new to programming.

Comment: I haven't used r before, so beyond the = thing it's a new question and now I'm a little out of my depth.  That said, you're setting v_t = 0 and then returning (v_t), so you should indeed be getting x = (0) for timepoint < 55 and timepoint > 235.

Comment: True, but it doesn't produce a vector with all values including the zeros for those timepoints. I think this question doesn't belong to R only as most of the function structures should be the same.

Comment: Oh, well I actually don't see the return of your for loop, only the return of vax_fun.  If you want to return a list made up of the outputs in the for loop, you should initialize the list before the for loop, and then append x to the list for each cycle.  Then return the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the results on every pass through the loop:

```
y <- NULL
for (timepoint in 1:365){
  x = vax_fun(timepoint, parms1)
  y <- c(y, x)
}
str(y)
#  num [1:365] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
summary(y)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#  -279.2     0.0     0.0  3528.5   123.4 25972.3
```